# getting started with admob for android - confused about documentation

Tags: android, installation, admob

I just started looking into putting Admob ads into the android app I'm building.  So far, no good.  I've been following the example in the AdMod_Android_SDK_Instructions.pdf that I downloaded from the adMob website, but am confused.  On page 7 I see the import statements refer to the package as com.admob.android.ads - but in the SDK I downloaded, the package is com.google.ads - is this a leftover from before google acquired admob?  It then goes on to call the method a`dView.requestFreshAd()`; - which does not exist in the latest code.
Please can someone help me out with some code that actually works?  My specific errors from logcat are:

AdView missing required XML attribute adUnitId.

... then after I call `adView.loadAd(new AdRequest())`; i get:

```
Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type.  Is your ad unit Id correct?
onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Google Ad request).
```

Any help, much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: ah ha!  finally from finding someone else's xml I have figured out what I was doing wrong.  I had this line: xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/...my package name - in the main LinearLayout of my app, when it should have been in the AdView part of the xml.  wow.  so glad I figured that out after sooo many hours of googling!

Answer (score 12):

As of 4.1.0,

mob1lejunkie is perfectly right, you can remove

- attrs.xml
- background, primarytextcolor, secondarytextcolor attributes (and define them from admob web site on the manage setting tab of your app)
- remove the name space xmlns:myapp from your main layout in your xml file and replace it by xmlns:ads (take care here !! The new xmlns is not in /apk/res but apk/lib )
- change the namespace of adUnitID and adSize in the adView xml snippet

so here is a working xml snippet with admob 4.1.0 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="a14d7f7d2180609"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Isn't it a bit light from google to ask devs to put in place a new code and use a librairy that is not yet documented by google themselves ? It reminds me of the adwhirl adventure...

Nevertheless, I must say I am glad google put that in place and remove the attrs.xml stuff. It is much easier to use admob with project inheritance in android.

Also, with respect to using multiple adviews in a project, please note that with this release, it is now possible to add you admob id in the strings.xml file of your application as requested on this thread : http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/c57917b4491a0c1

Just put it this way in your xml layouts for all your adviews :

```
ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id"
```

and then

```
<string name="admob_unit_id">a14d7f7d2180609</string>
```

in your strings.xml file and all other localized versions of this file.
This will give you a single centralized location to enter your admob id in all your views.

Great release indeed.

Regards, 
 Steff

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "It reminds me of the adwhirl adventure..."? I am currently getting the same error when trying to implement adwhirl in my code, and i have a suspicion that it has something to do with my adUnitId.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue with 4.1.0 and it turns out **Admob documentation (as of 15th May) is out of date.**

`attrs.xml` is no longer needed and the namespace in the layout needs to be

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads
```

rater then the old

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.your.packagename
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the PDF is outdated.

Try reading [Google AdMob Ads Android Fundamentals](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html)

Comment: Thanks SteD - so that stuff's all looking good, but I still get the logcat errors in my original question and that failedtoreceivead... so back to the googling for me!

Comment: weird.  my publisher id is correct for sure.  so I wonder why i'm getting this "Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit Id correct?" line in logcat.  google turns up no matches for the error!  I can't be the only one to experience this!  argh!

Comment: hallelujah!  my answer was to create a new attr in attrs.xml called adUnitId and then setting it to my publisher id in my layout xml!  omg... i have seen this code nowhere in all the searching i've been doing all day!  i can't believe it worked!  woop!

Comment: woah I'm glad it works, I'm actually still using the old package com.admob.android.ads

Comment: for me, it was being caused by eclipse error. something like: "Attempted to beginRule: P/..., does not match outer scope rule". eclipse restart worked

Answer (score 1):

This page helped me with with placing an ad in the XML layout:  http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html