# utilities of AdWhirl over other ads Network

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me what are the advantages of using Adwhirl in comparism to AdMob,Millenial,Google AdSense for Mobile Applications,ZestADZ.Is there any disadvantage if i use AdMob or ZestADZ instead of AdWhirl...

with regards
Anshuman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is off-topic, but the advantage is that Adwhirl precisely rotate between all those ads providers for you.

When one doesn't provide any ad, it will display another ad from another network.

Nevertheless, adwhirl API is really poorly documented and I would say "for experts" only. It took me quite a lot of time to make it working with admob,millenia and two others. And the result gave me the feeling of a week app.

I decided to add these feature myself, rotating ads from 2 main providers that pay well per click and have good geographic coverage (mobfox and admob).

But now, I am not even sure adwhirl is still actively maintained by admob, and moreover, mobfox or admob allow for a "backfill" option that does almost the same, they provide ads from other networks when they don't have any ad for you. For admob it's google ads, and mobfox allows ads from admob.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: thats means its better to use admob or mobfox instead of adwhirl..

Comment: would you provide me any documents regarding the use of this ads network..actually i search in google ..but what there present is not understand by me..so if you dont mind do you have some documentations regarding this topic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320186/getting-started-with-admob-for-android-confused-about-documentation/6017266#6017266

Comment: yeh i have gone through this and implemented the code as there shown in the example..its running fine but its doesnt show any add..the layout position where i put the add is comming blank..is it becoz i dont have given any publisher_id in the code..

Comment: for sure ! You need an id to receive ads, even for tests.

Comment: ok..thanks for all..can i get your email id..

Comment: you could find following my app in my profile but I can't write it down here.